# Vue JS Keep all imports in different file

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

Iam learning vuejs, i have hundreds of json file i want to load in to my Vue project ,
in my script, Simply i can do this loading all json files directly in main file
as below

```
//Index.vue
<script>
import data1 from 'assets/json/data1.json';
import data2 from 'assets/json/data2.json';
...
```

above works fine, but now im planning to keep all imports into different file
as below

```
//assets/imports.js
import data1 from 'assets/json/data1.json';
import data2 from 'assets/json/data2.json';
```

and refer imports.js as

```
//Index.vue
<script>
import alldata from 'assets/imports'
```

is it possible to do like this, in not good in webpack too

Comment: Yes you can, simply merge all of your data in an object or array in the imports.js, then export the resulting object/array as default export

Comment: could you pls post this as anwser

Comment: your suggestion helped me, why dont you add some code in your answer as example, it will help others, i will accept as correct answer

Answer (score 1):

As requested, posting this as an answer:

Yes you can, simply merge all of your data in an object or array in the imports.js, then export the resulting object/array as default export

Comment: ok. so import.j = export default alldata,then in hello.vue, import alldata from 'assets/imports', its returns error